# Unit tests running phantomJS run much slower on windows than iOS/Linux

Tags: windows, angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have an angular app that I have been developing on a Windows machine. For a long time I have felt that the unit tests took way longer to run on windows than I was used to them taking on previous projects I developed on a Mac, but this is a different code base so I chalked it up to that. However Today I got my hands on a mac to do some testing and I can confirm a huge difference in run time even though the windows machine is a far more powerful machine.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so was there anything you found to improve test performance on windows?

Windows 10 completes 448 tests in 8 minutes 28 seconds. (2.8 Ghz processor w/ 32 GB of ram)
[image]

I decided to see how long they took to run on Windows if I used Chrome instead of PhantomJS and the tests completed in 1 minute and 4 seconds, so this seems to be an issue with PhantomJS not Karma/jasmine.
[image]

iOS High Sierra completes 445 (I'm not sure why it's a different number) tests in 1 minutes 50 seconds (2.6 Ghz processor w/ 8 GB of ram)
[image]

Our build server running linux completes 448 tests in 1 minute 22 seconds (T2.Large instance from AWS split between 6 Docker containers, only one of which is running the tests)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 127.0.0.1 or just localhost(or uncomment the line with it) to windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file.

Remember to open that file with administrator permissions.